# How do I access a data path?

Tags: android, logcat, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

So I have all the information I need regarding the data path because it was answered in another question. My problem is that I’m very very new and I don’t understand where I’m supposed to enter the text in order to actually get to the information.

This is the text:

```
private String getFilePath(){
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File filePath = contextWrapper.getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(filePath,"fileName" +"*/*");
    return file.getPath();
}
```

- obviously with my own file name, which I got from logcat -

Where do I input that in order to access the information? Like I said, I’m very new and would appreciate if anyone could “dumb it down” for me.

Additional information that may or not be useful:

- I’m using a Samsung Galaxy a12
- Device is not rooted

I haven’t really tried anything yet.

Comment: `This is the text:` You mean: `This is the code:`

Comment: `"fileName" +"*/*"` It is pretty unclear what you wanna do. You cannot use `*/*` there. Do you wanna read a file? Create a file? We have no idea what you mean with all information about a data path. And please dont refer to another post without link.

Comment: What information do you want to access? what is the "all the information" that you have? can you add the question url that you said " it was answered in another question" ?

Comment: The content within the data path is what I’m trying to access, I’m sorry for not posting the link- I’ll remember next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the data path using the provided code, you need to follow these steps:

Open your Android project in an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) such as Android Studio.
Locate the class where you want to access the data path. It's usually a Java file with the extension ".java".
Within that class, you need to add a method that includes the provided code snippet. Here's an example:

```
  public class YourClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ... your existing code ...

    private String getFilePath(){
        ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File filePath = contextWrapper.getFilesDir();
        File file = new File(filePath,"fileName");
        return file.getPath();
    }

    // ... your existing code ...
}
```

In the above code, make sure you replace "fileName" with the actual name of the file you obtained from Logcat.
Once you have added this method to your class, you can call it from another method or wherever you need to access the data path. For example, you can call it from the onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    String dataPath = getFilePath();
    // Now you can use the 'dataPath' variable to access the data path.
    // For example, you can display it in a TextView or use it for file operations.
}
```

Replace "your_layout" with the actual layout file name you are using for your activity.
After performing these steps and running your app on your Samsung Galaxy A12, the getFilePath() method should be called, and it will return the data path. You can then use the returned path to access the desired information or perform any necessary file operations.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! Could I also do this using adbd (I recently taught myself how to do that) or would I need to stick with downloading android studio?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please just mark it as an answer, and this question I didn't get your question well